# Fourier Transform of 3D data set

Tags: java, math, fft

I have a data set which is spaced regular in every dimension (equidistant).
But the spacing of the dimensions is different.

dx != dy != dz (!=  -> is not)

I fourier transform this data set and than filter it.
Where for the wavenumbers I take into account the different spacing.
Afterwards I transform the data back. 
This seems to give results wich I exspect, but i am still doubting if this is correct.

My question is now: does it matter that the spacing is not the same in the 3 dimesnions?

This is al implemented in java with j-transforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take spacing difference into account when you are building filter in wavenumber space, if its kernel depends on dimensional parameters.

For example, if spacings are `dx, dy=Fyx*dx, dz=Fzx*dx`, and you **need isotropic filtration**, then in k-space you might use  `kx, ky/Fyx, kz/Fzx`

Comment: Thanx fo the reply. So I need to take this into account with teh wavenumbers like this for example, K_x =  constant/(Nx dx), K_y =  constant/(Ny dy), K_z =  constant/(Nz dz)?  Or do I need to take into account something more?

Comment: With kernel you mean the transformation from 1 space to the other (cartesian to wavenumber)?

Comment: @Gijs Den Hollander Kernel of filter in w/n space `...and than filter it.`

Comment: How should I go about taking to acount the difference spacing because I still do not understand. My filter is ->  i*4Pi*kz/(sqrt(kx^2+ky^2+kz^2)^2). And the wavenumbers are implemeted as above. How do i find the kernel of the filter? is some scalling that i need to do?

Comment: Wrote my suggestion. I still don't sure that you need isotropic filtering (and it is applicable to you filtering process at all)